# Why [formControl] is changing value type on change?

Tags: forms, angular

I'm working with Angular2 Form Builder and I found a tricky situation. I've got this form builder instance:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  limit: null
});
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<input type="number [formControl]="form.controls['limit']">
```

As you can see, my initial value is `null` and it's required by my backend. One of the first action in my component is `patchValue` on my `form` where I set `limit` to 5 (5 is a number). But then, when I change limit value to 10, its changed type from number to string.

Why does it happen? Why type is changing from number (which is desired) to string? Is there any way to enforce number type?

Comment: Seems to work fine here... (check console) http://plnkr.co/edit/xrUDqEvCmnFhLsSVUqLC?p=preview

Comment: I just took the code you have provided and tested it. I cannot know how the rest of your code looks like. You'd have to elaborate more to get some kind of useful answer then ;)

Comment: I found a real problem and it's not about [formControl]. Everything because I'm setting input type dynamically based on data from backend. 

From API I get a list of controls and I loop through that list. For each iteration I create a control with specific type - text or number. Even if I set type to number, Angular2 ignore this type at treat it like a string (in HTML I can see that type is set properly so I can't type any letters inside).

Here is a plunkr that reproduce my problem http://plnkr.co/edit/KNoFaFJ1BPbuxGQu5mQk?p=preview. Is there any way to enforce Angular to use proper type?